# How to convert public to private ip?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I convert the Public IP of an Amazon instance to its private IP? given that I am on the same subnet as the host I am resolving the IP address for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon EC2 API shows how to get the private IP addresses assigned to an Elastic IP address here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeAddresses.html

The key bit of info looks to be here:
ec2-describe-addresses --filter "public-ip="

To do this in Java the DescribeAddressRequest looks like the implementation of the API that describes the attributes of the Elastic IP

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeAddressesRequest.html